# how can i print students degree with a function when user entered the degree through prompt?

Tags: javascript

this is my code i need the answer like this .. i need the user who entered the degree in prompt

```
function result(degree){

    var x = 100;
 
    if( x >=85&& x <100){
        document.write("excellent");
    } else if (x>= 75 && x <=85){
        document.write("very good ");
    } else if ( x >=65 && x<=75){
        document.write(" good ");
    } else if (x >=50 && x <=65){
        document.write("fairly good");
    } else if (x <50 ){
        document.write("fail");
    }
}
        
var deg = prompt(" enter the degree ");
document.write(result(deg));
```

Comment: Your code looks incomplete. How are you identifying and storing the user? Is this a web app?

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from the function. And trying write on document in inside the function.
if you are up to showing result based on the prompt input then your code should be as follows:

```
function result(deg)
{

    var txt = "";

    if( deg >= 85 && deg < 100){
      txt = "excellent";
    } else if (deg >= 75 && deg <=85){
       txt = "very good ";
    } else if ( deg >=65 && deg <= 75){
       txt = " good ";
    } else if (deg >= 50 && deg <= 65){
       txt = "fairly good";
    } else if (deg < 50 ){
       txt = "fail";
    }
    
    return txt;
  
}

        
var deg = prompt(" enter the degree ");
var degree_result = result(deg);

document.write(degree_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to the `return the degree to print on the page`.  try as follows

```js
function result(degree){
    if( degree >= 85 && degree < 100){
        return "excellent";
    } else if (degree >= 75 && degree <= 85){
        return "very good ";
    } else if ( degree >= 65 && degree <= 75){
        return "good";
    } else if (degree >= 50 && degree <= 65){
        return "fairly good";
    } else if (degree < 50 ){
        return "fail";
    }
}
        
var deg = prompt(" enter the degree ");
document.write(result(deg));
```